# What do you call the non-buisness logic of an application?

Tags: business-logic, concept

I am currently working on a project that can have a few UI and OS customization depending on the clients country.
It affects things like logos, texts and small functionality. The core of the app remains the same.

So, what do you call this?

I've heard people calling it "clothing" but I'm not sure it is the correct technical term.
Thank you!

Comment: Some might call it "localization", I guess.

Comment: I would call it `extras` or `miscellaneous` . `target` could be an option, but in some frameworks it is used as folder to locate the binaries.